# Rails: Can I have different views based on the time of the day?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to create an ordering page for a food truck that will only display during certain hours of the day. I know it's probably possible but I'm not sure how to implement it. The time has to be based on the "real time" (probably like GMT) rather than the user's local time.

I'm thinking in the controller, it will check the "real time" and render one page if it falls within the time frame, or another page if the time falls outside of the time frame.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That sounds like exactly what you should do. Do you have a question about rendering those pages?

Comment: Seeing how Rails is centered around MVC, yes.  You would handle this through your controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Rails `Time` method can help with this. Here's an example of a code snippet you can drop directly into a controller action:

```
now = Time.now
start_of_day = now.at_midnight 
time_at_noon = start_of_day + 43200 # 12hr * 60min * 60sec

if now > time_at_noon
  render template: "after_noon"
else
  render template: "before_noon"
end
```

Of course, you'll want to make calculations based on the time you're looking to parse at.

Also, if you're going to apply this logic across controllers, you'll probably want to look at abstracting this into a module.

**UPDATE**:

If you want to normalize all your times to UTC, you'll want to wrap the entire snippet above within a block that explicitly declares the timezone (naturally, you'll need to convert your desired local times to UTC):

```
Time.use_zone('UTC') do
  # above code goes here
end
```

Comment: `code`   
def pickup
    Time.use_zone('UTC') do
      now = Time.now
      start_of_day = now.at_midnight
      eightam = start_of_day + 28800 # 8am = 8 * 60 * 60
      onepm = start_of_day + 46800 # 1pm = 13 * 60 * 60

      if now > eightam && now < onepm
        render "pickup"
      else
        render "closed"
      end
    end
  end
`code`

Comment: I think you have to use `now = Time.zone.now`

Comment: Yes, you're probably right. If you're invoking the `now` method on `Time` within a timezone specific block, you should use `Time.zone.now`.

Comment: it's also very weird.  my dev set up gives a different time than heroku. still playing with it right now to get it to work.

Comment: Your machine gives you its localized time, which is probably different from Heroku's localized time. You can normalize across all these by simply determining the UTC equivalent of the local time.